# How do I make all my IMAP folders siblings (instead of children) of Inbox?

Tags: thunderbird, imap

My mail account (IMAP) has this folder structure in Thunderbird:

- Inbox

  - Drafts
  - Sent
  - Junk
  - Trash
  - various custom folders …

As you can see, all folders are actually sub-folders of "Inbox". However, I want all folders to be on the same level:

- Inbox
- Drafts
- Sent
- Junk
- Trash
- various custom folders …

At <kbd>Account Settings → Server Settings → Advanced…</kbd>, the field "**Personal namespace**" has the value `"INBOX/"`. Is this the place I need to fiddle with? Or do I have to add a value in the field "**IMAP server directory**" (which is empty)?

I have another hosting account at the same webhoster and there all my folders are on the same level. The only difference in the mentionend settings: "**Personal namespace**" has the value `""`. I tried to use this value in my problematic account, too, restarted TB, but it has no effect on the folders. This unproblematic account runs on a newer server version, though.

What can I do so that all folders are siblings of Inbox, not children?

Comment: I think you probably have to change this on the server side, not in Thunderbird. In IMAP it's the server that tells the client what the hierarchical structure of the folders is.

Comment: Can't you just drag-n-drop them in TB's folder view frame to be where you want?

Comment: @martineau depending on the server configuration, moving the folders may change how they behave too.

Comment: @martineau: No, when I try to drop it before or after the Inbox, nothing happens. When I try to drop it at the account name, I get the warning: `The current command did not succeed. … [ALREADYEXISTS] Mailbox already exists: INBOX/test.`

Comment: @Celada: But isn't that the purpose of the mentioned configuration options? I don't necessarily want to change this on the server side; it would be sufficient if it would only work in TB locally.

Comment: @unor: Sorry, you cant drag-n-drop as I suggested -- I receive the same error. Instead you can create new folders at the account name level by right-clicking on it and picking "New Folder". Afterwards you should be able to drag the contents from the like-named nested folder to it's upper-level counterpart. Not ideal, but it'll get you there...

Comment: @martineau: I tried that. When I right-click the account name and create a new folder, this folder automatically gets created as a child of Inbox. (This is not the case for the accounts I don't have a problem with.)

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the "IMAP Server Directory" field in Account Settings. This corrected it for me.

In Linux (should be very similar in Windows):

> Edit | Account Settings | Server Settings | Advanced | IMAP Server Directory

Insert [Gmail] - with the square brackets - and restart Thunderbird.

Comment: What should I enter there? It’s empty currently. I’m not using GMail.